# How to support mxf file formats in mediafoundation source Reader and sink writer

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am  creating a transcoder application using windows mediafoundation API. I am using Source Reader and Sink Writer API's for transcoding. Now I need to add support for media types like(.mxf) , which is not supported by mediafoundation . Media foundation documentation says, "Third parties can support additional formats by writing custom plug-ins." Can anyone help with documentations or example on how to get started writing custom plug ins.

Answer (score 3):

You need your own implementation of `IMFMediaSource` to read such files and `IMFMediaSink` to write.

For sources, MSDN entry points are:

- [Writing a Custom Media Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/writing-a-custom-media-source)
- [Case Study: MPEG-1 Media Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--writing-a-custom-media-source) and there is a source code in the form of a [mpeg1source sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/mpeg1source)

For sinks it is:

- [Media Sinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-sinks)

Your implementation of Media Foundation primitives could be used with higher level APIs like Source Reader, Sink Writer and also Media Foundation Media Session.

The samples also include [wavsource](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/wavsource) and [wavsink](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/wavsink) which are also good examples for the mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do we implement decoder,from which we can get uncompressed data and pass on to sink writer?

Comment: Support for formats and media sources as primitives are not supposed to include decoding. It is assumed that such third party extension would rather enable demultiplexing into certain well known format like H.264 (or custom format can be here as well). Then another MF primitive such as decoder would jump in and handle decompression. This way it would be possible to have new container formats work with stock (esp. HW accelerated) decoders. Still it's your plugin: you can have decompression right there as well.